PrimeVue tailwindcss Timeline eventseperator style missing
I'm using PrimeVue with Tailwindcss based on tailwind.primevue. I try using the Timeline component from Lara preset. It's weird that its eventseperator is missing. Any help is appreciated.
tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    './index.html',
    './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './node_modules/primevue/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: 'rgb(var(--primary))',
        'primary-inverse': 'rgb(var(--primary-inverse))',
        'primary-hover': 'rgb(var(--primary-hover))',
        'primary-active-color': 'rgb(var(--primary-active-color))',

        'primary-highlight': 'rgb(var(--primary)/var(--primary-highlight-opacity))',
        'primary-highlight-inverse': 'rgb(var(--primary-highlight-inverse))',
        'primary-highlight-hover': 'rgb(var(--primary)/var(--primary-highlight-hover-opacity))',

        'primary-50': 'rgb(var(--primary-50))',
        'primary-100': 'rgb(var(--primary-100))',
        'primary-200': 'rgb(var(--primary-200))',
        'primary-300': 'rgb(var(--primary-300))',
        'primary-400': 'rgb(var(--primary-400))',
        'primary-500': 'rgb(var(--primary-500))',
        'primary-600': 'rgb(var(--primary-600))',
        'primary-700': 'rgb(var(--primary-700))',
        'primary-800': 'rgb(var(--primary-800))',
        'primary-900': 'rgb(var(--primary-900))',
        'primary-950': 'rgb(var(--primary-950))',

        'surface-0': 'rgb(var(--surface-0))',
        'surface-50': 'rgb(var(--surface-50))',
        'surface-100': 'rgb(var(--surface-100))',
        'surface-200': 'rgb(var(--surface-200))',
        'surface-300': 'rgb(var(--surface-300))',
        'surface-400': 'rgb(var(--surface-400))',
        'surface-500': 'rgb(var(--surface-500))',
        'surface-600': 'rgb(var(--surface-600))',
        'surface-700': 'rgb(var(--surface-700))',
        'surface-800': 'rgb(var(--surface-800))',
        'surface-900': 'rgb(var(--surface-900))',
        'surface-950': 'rgb(var(--surface-950))'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: []
}

main.ts
const app = createApp(App)

app.use(PrimeVue, {
  ripple: true,
  unstyled: true,
  pt: Lara
});
app.use(router)

app.component('Timeline', Timeline)
app.component('Galleria', Galleria)

postcss.config.js
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}

main.css
@import './base.css';

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html {
  font-size: 14px;
}
// rest of styles

MyTimeline.vue
<template>
  <div
    ref="el"
    :class="['card transition-all duration-500', isVisible ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0']"
  >
    <Timeline :value="events" class="w-full md:w-[20rem] items-center">
      <template #opposite="slotProps">
        <small class="text-surface-600">{{ slotProps.item.date }}</small>
      </template>
      <template #content="slotProps">
        {{ slotProps.item.status }}
      </template>
    </Timeline>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useElementVisibility } from '@vueuse/core'

const el = ref(null)
const isVisible = useElementVisibility(el)
const events = ref([
  { status: 'Ordered', date: '15/10/2020 10:30', icon: 'pi pi-shopping-cart', color: '#9C27B0' },
  { status: 'Processing', date: '15/10/2020 14:00', icon: 'pi pi-cog', color: '#673AB7' },
  { status: 'Shipped', date: '15/10/2020 16:15', icon: 'pi pi-shopping-cart', color: '#FF9800' },
  { status: 'Delivered', date: '16/10/2020 10:00', icon: 'pi pi-check', color: '#607D8B' }
])
</script>

I've tried to inspect the element I see the div have no style applied though I checked the Timeline in Lara preset file the style exists. Same thing happened for Aura preset.
Web Inspect on Timeline
separator: ({ props }) => ({
    class: [
      'flex items-center flex-initial',
      {
        'flex-col': props.layout === 'vertical',
        'flex-row': props.layout === 'horizontal'
      }
    ]
  }),
  marker: {
    class: [
      'flex self-baseline',
      'w-4 h-4',
      'rounded-full border-2 border-primary bg-surface-0 dark:bg-surface-900/40'
    ]
  },

